# Jackson Json: How to get multiple values with same name from json node java

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonnode

I have a Json String that looks like this:

```
{
 "generatedList1":{"myList":["1","2","3","4"]},
 "generatedList2":{"myList":["1","6","8","2"]},
 "generatedList3":{"myList":["1","12","3","11"]}
}
```

I want to collect all the values that are there in all of `myList`
i.e. `[1,2,3,4,6,8,11,12]`

I converted the string to `JsonNode` and then did `JsonNode.findValues("myList")` which returns `List<JsonNode>`.
But when I try to convert each `JsonNode` to `String` I get double quotes and square brackets as part of the `String` and not just numbers.
I can remove that from the `String` but it seems hacky.
I am sure there has to be a direct way to do this.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add your actual code to the question (properly formatted with the `{}` button). It sounds like you are using the `JsonNode` directly instead of the `List` that you got. Why?

Comment: I was iterating through each node and for each node i was doing mapper.writeValueAsString(node); This String had double quotes and square brackets.
Solution by Apoorv worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `JsonNode.findValues("myList")` returns a List of JsonNode.

You can iterate on each of these JsonNode objects and convert them into `List<Integer>` easily by:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Integer> list = mapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<List<Integer>>(){}).readValue(jsonNode);
```

You can then combine these lists of `Integers` to find the unique integers present.

Comment: did you try that? because the lists contain `String` values and I doubt if Jackson is that smart to parse them into integers

Comment: Yeah, I tried it out using the Json string `"[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\"]"`, and it works as expected, returning a list of integers.